# How to decrease number [value] before post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure but is it possible if user type numbers in input, i want to decrease the number in hidden before post? for example if type 1 then output 0 or if type 2 then output 1

```
<input class="decrease" type="text" name="number" value="" />
<input class="output" type="hidden" name="number" value="//decrease number//" />
```

Comment: it is possible, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know bro i am new in javascript or jquery. @depperm

Comment: @FOOUTY, you want to decrease the number and show the decreased number in the textbox in which the user types? or show it somewhere else ?

Comment: If someone type 2 i want to auto decrease the number to 1 in hidden input before user post @HariRam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this one helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.decrease').keyup(function(){
        if($('.decrease').val()!="")
        {
            $('.output').val($('.decrease').val()-1);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.output').val("");
        } 
    });
});
```

You have to make sure that the user types in only numbers. If the user types in a character, the value of the hidden input will be NaN.

See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) for more examples and information.

Comment: Working but  if i type first 1 and remove it then output show -1. is there way to leave blank if someone first type number then remove the number then output need to leave blank?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.decrease').on('keyup',function(){
        decrease();
    });
});

    function decrease(){
      number = $('.decrease').val();
      
      $('.output').val(number-1);
      if(number == ''){
          $('.output').val('');
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input class="decrease" type="text" name="number" />
    <input class="output" type="hidden" name="number" value="5" />
      <input type="button" value="Submit" />
      </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way without onclick? I want like jquery keyup.. @Keerthi

Comment: When i type 2 then why output show -2 ? i want if i type 2 then output need 1 @Keerthi

Comment: Now working but if i type first 1 and remove it then output show -1. is there way to leave blank if someone first type number then remove the number then output need to leave blank?